# How can I retrieve comments from my Facebook Live stream and import as an OBS source?

Tags: html, facebook, comments, live-streaming, obs

I'm trying to find a way to grab comments from my Facebook Live video and have them available as a source in OBS so I can display or broadcast them. I found this example that works to some extent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Facebook Live Comments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html,
        body,
        #comments {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        html {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #comments {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 8px 16px 8px 8px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }

        .comment {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .comment:first-child {
            margin-top: auto;
        }

        .comment:not(:last-child) {
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }

        /**
         * Prevent clipped comment
         * margin-bottom: #comments padding-bottom + .comment margin-bottom
         */
        .comment:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }

        .comment__name {
            flex: 0 1;
            white-space: nowrap;
            color: #2196F3;
        }

        .comment__name::after {
            content: ": ";
            white-space: pre;
        }

        .comment__message {
            flex: 1 0;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow:
                -1px -1px 0 #000,
                1px -1px 0 #000,
                -1px 1px 0 #000,
                1px 1px 0 #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="comments"></div>
</body>
<script>
  const videoId = ""; // ID of your live video
  const accessToken = ""; // Get one on the developer page

  const source = new EventSource(`https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/${videoId}/live_comments?access_token=${accessToken}&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name},message`);
  const comments = document.getElementById("comments");

  function appendComment(comment) {
    const newComment = document.createElement("div");
    newComment.classList.add("comment");

    const commentName = document.createElement("div");
    commentName.classList.add("comment__name")
    commentName.textContent = comment.from.name;

    const commentMessage = document.createElement("div");
    commentMessage.classList.add("comment__message");
    commentMessage.textContent = comment.message;

    newComment.appendChild(commentName);
    newComment.appendChild(commentMessage);

    comments.appendChild(newComment);

    comments.scrollTop = comments.scrollHeight;
  }

  // Get last 10 comments
  fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/${videoId}/comments?access_token=${accessToken}&summary=true&limit=10`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    res.data.forEach(comment => appendComment(comment));
  });

  // Listen for new comments
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    appendComment(data);
  };
</script>
</html>
```

So, if I add in my video ID and access token and open the html file in a browser or OBS, it will show any comments already posted, but it won't update to show new ones unless I manually refresh the page. It seems like this code should be able to retrieve new comments, but I can't tell why it doesn't or if there are any errors in it.

What can I do to get this working? Or, is there another better way altogether?

Comment: It seems I overlooked something! I had this html file as a browser source in OBS with the local filepath entered in the URL box. The file displayed, but wouldn't refresh. I noticed the "Local file" checkbox and hit that, and suddenly the display is updating with new comments like it's supposed to! I don't know why Chrome isn't refreshing automatically, but OBS is what I was trying to use anyway.

Comment: Graph API Live Video Comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/comments/